# Howto get Glassfish to honor endpoint-address-uri definition?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

It seems like Glassfish 3 deploys my Java EE 6 webservice to the wrong URL when I am using an endpointInterface definition and I am not able to figure out why. This is what I have go so far:

I have a webservice definition like the following:

```
@WebService(name = "HelloService")
public interface HelloService
{
    @WebMethod
    String sayHello(String name);
}
```

And an implementation of the service as stateless EJB:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "HelloWebService", portName = "HelloServicePort", endpointInterface = "helloServicePackage.HelloService")
@Stateless
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService
{
    public String sayHello(String name)
    {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

For deployment on Glassfish I use a sun-ejb-jar.xml:

```
<sun-ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
    <ejb>
            <ejb-name>HelloServiceImpl</ejb-name>
            ...
            <webservice-endpoint>
                <port-component-name>
                    HelloService
                </port-component-name>
                <endpoint-address-uri>
                    Services/HelloService
                </endpoint-address-uri>
            </webservice-endpoint>
        </ejb>
    </enterprise-beans>
</sun-ejb-jar>
```

Then Gassfish deploys my service to the URL //HelloWebService/HelloServiceImpl which is not what I intended.

However if I leave out the endpointInterface definition and use a name on the service implementation directly like

```
@WebService(serviceName = "HelloWebService", portName = "HelloServicePort", name= "HelloService")
@Stateless
public class HelloServiceImpl
{
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String name)
    {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

Then the service is correctly deployed to //Services/HelloService

How do I have to modify the annotations/sun-ejb-jar.xml so that the deployment also works with an endpointInterface in use?

Regards, Tilmann